# Вывод слова если в нем есть цифра

Tags: c++

Как вывести из строки слова в которых есть цифра?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main() {
string str;
cin >> str;

int len = str.length();
}
```

Comment: Пока что вы считали одно-единственное слово...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов много. Вот один из них:

```
string str;
//просто cin >> str читает до символа разделителья, поэтому:
getline(cin, str); 
size_t p = 0, sz = 0;
const char delim = ' ';
while (sz != str.npos) {
    p = str.find_first_not_of(delim, sz);
    if (p == str.npos) break;
    sz = str.find(delim, p);
    std::string s = str.substr(p, sz - p);
    const size_t len = s.length();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) {
            std::cout << s << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тогда еще вариант со строковым потоком. Переписав функцию checkWord вы получите решение другой задачи со словами

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


bool checkWord(string word) {
    int i = 0;
    int flag = false;
    while (i < word.length() && flag == false) {
        if (word[i] >= '0' && word[i] <= '9') {
            flag = true;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
int main()

{
    string str;
    string word;
    cout << "str= ";
    getline(cin,str);
    stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    while (ss >> word) {
        if (checkWord(word) == true) {
            cout << word << endl;
        }
    }


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```